# How to check web host environment on a server?

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I've got a .NET Core API that uses Swagger UI if the web host environment is in development like so.

```
        if (env.IsDevelopment() || env.IsEnvironment(ServiceCollectionExtensions.IsolatedEnvironmentName) || env.IsEnvironment(ServiceCollectionExtensions.LocalEnvironmentName))
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API");
                c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            });
        }
```

For some reason the Swagger UI returns a 404 so I'm wondering what environment the API is running under. How can I confirm this and change it?

Answer (score 0):

use environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to control it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is set by the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`.

You can view or change the current state of this variable in the `launchSettings.json` file.

For development it should look like this:

`"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"`

Comment: So there are a number of appsettings files in the API folder but no launchSettings.json file.

Comment: It is in the `Properties` folder. If you are using Visual Studio you can also set an env variable when you right click on you projects and choose properties.

Comment: It's an API that's deployed on a server.

Comment: you might want to check the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable on that server. If it is not set, then the value is `Production` by default.